# Error during git push heroku master: NameError: uninitialized constant User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

UGH - running into error trying to deploy to heroku:

```
Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       rake aborted!
       NameError: uninitialized constant User
       /tmp/build_7dea9fa4-7a4b-4b88-8edf-da4e74529549/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:238:in `const_get'
       /tmp/build_7dea9fa4-7a4b-4b88-8edf-da4e74529549/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:238:in `block in constantize'
       /tmp/build_7dea9fa4-7a4b-4b88-8edf-da4e74529549/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:236:in `each'
       /tmp/build_7dea9fa4-7a4b-4b88-8edf-da4e74529549/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:236:in `inject'
       /tmp/build_7dea9fa4-7a4b-4b88-8edf-da4e74529549/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:236:in `constantize'
       /tmp/build_7dea9fa4-7a4b-4b88-8edf-da4e74529549/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise.rb:297:in `get'
       /tmp/build_7dea9fa4-7a4b-4b88-8edf-da4e74529549/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise/mapping.rb:77:in `to'
       /tmp/build_7dea9fa4-7a4b-4b88-8edf-da4e74529549/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise/mapping.rb:72:in `modules'
       /tmp/build_7dea9fa4-7a4b-4b88-8edf-da4e74529549/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise/mapping.rb:89:in `routes'
       /tmp/build_7dea9fa4-7a4b-4b88-8edf-da4e74529549/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise/mapping.rb:156:in `default_used_route'
       /tmp/build_7dea9fa4-7a4b-4b88-8edf-da4e74529549/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise/mapping.rb:66:in `initialize'
       /tmp/build_7dea9fa4-7a4b-4b88-8edf-da4e74529549/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise.rb:331:in `new'
       /tmp/build_7dea9fa4-7a4b-4b88-8edf-da4e74529549/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise.rb:331:in `add_mapping'
       /tmp/build_7dea9fa4-7a4b-4b88-8edf-da4e74529549/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:221:in `block in devise_for'
       /tmp/build_7dea9fa4-7a4b-4b88-8edf-da4e74529549/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:220:in `each'
       /tmp/build_7dea9fa4-7a4b-4b88-8edf-da4e74529549/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:220:in `devise_for'
       /tmp/build_7dea9fa4-7a4b-4b88-8edf-da4e74529549/config/routes.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_7dea9fa4-7a4b-4b88-8edf-da4e74529549/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:335:in `instance_exec'
       /tmp/build_7dea9fa4-7a4b-4b88-8edf-da4e74529549/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:335:in `eval_block'
       /tmp/build_7dea9fa4-7a4b-4b88-8edf-da4e74529549/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:313:in `draw'
       /tmp/build_7dea9fa4-7a4b-4b88-8edf-da4e74529549/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_7dea9fa4-7a4b-4b88-8edf-da4e74529549/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
       /tmp/build_7dea9fa4-7a4b-4b88-8edf-da4e74529549/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
       /tmp/build_7dea9fa4-7a4b-4b88-8edf-da4e74529549/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
       /tmp/build_7dea9fa4-7a4b-4b88-8edf-da4e74529549/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
       /tmp/build_7dea9fa4-7a4b-4b88-8edf-da4e74529549/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
       /tmp/build_7dea9fa4-7a4b-4b88-8edf-da4e74529549/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `call'
       /tmp/build_7dea9fa4-7a4b-4b88-8edf-da4e74529549/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `execute'
       /tmp/build_7dea9fa4-7a4b-4b88-8edf-da4e74529549/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
       /tmp/build_7dea9fa4-7a4b-4b88-8edf-da4e74529549/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:7:in `execute_if_updated'
       /tmp/build_7dea9fa4-7a4b-4b88-8edf-da4e74529549/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:71:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
       /tmp/build_7dea9fa4-7a4b-4b88-8edf-da4e74529549/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
       /tmp/build_7dea9fa4-7a4b-4b88-8edf-da4e74529549/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
       /tmp/build_7dea9fa4-7a4b-4b88-8edf-da4e74529549/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
       /tmp/build_7dea9fa4-7a4b-4b88-8edf-da4e74529549/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
       /tmp/build_7dea9fa4-7a4b-4b88-8edf-da4e74529549/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:288:in `initialize!'
       /tmp/build_7dea9fa4-7a4b-4b88-8edf-da4e74529549/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_7dea9fa4-7a4b-4b88-8edf-da4e74529549/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:264:in `require_environment!'
       /tmp/build_7dea9fa4-7a4b-4b88-8edf-da4e74529549/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:367:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
       /tmp/build_7dea9fa4-7a4b-4b88-8edf-da4e74529549/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:55:in `block (2 levels) in define'
       Tasks: TOP => environment
       (See full trace by running task with --trace)
 !
 !     Precompiling assets failed.
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app

To git@heroku.com:stark-badlands-3781.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:stark-badlands-3781.git'
```

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.1.0'
gem 'pg'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc
gem 'spring',                    group: :development
gem 'paperclip', '~> 4.1'
gem 'devise'
gem 'rails_12factor',            group: :production

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.1.0'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', '~> 2.6.1'
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :todo_lists
  has_many :todo_items
  has_many :paperclip_images
end
```

rake assets:precompile local:

```
I, [2014-06-20T15:37:13.385822 #11433]  INFO -- : Writing /Users/alissaStandard/Sites/webapps/tfmpm/public/assets/add-67105e31de9c7aab49163b845a818bce.png
I, [2014-06-20T15:37:13.388483 #11433]  INFO -- : Writing /Users/alissaStandard/Sites/webapps/tfmpm/public/assets/attachment-a525837b97fb7cf2a7523585123d98c8.png
I, [2014-06-20T15:37:13.389645 #11433]  INFO -- : Writing /Users/alissaStandard/Sites/webapps/tfmpm/public/assets/complete-b9f77b8fb4c417cc09d10f1a688fa81d.png
I, [2014-06-20T15:37:13.391336 #11433]  INFO -- : Writing /Users/alissaStandard/Sites/webapps/tfmpm/public/assets/delete-61a0b5a97ea630902c630a93f4ffc3d6.png
I, [2014-06-20T15:37:13.393294 #11433]  INFO -- : Writing /Users/alissaStandard/Sites/webapps/tfmpm/public/assets/dotplus_wallpaper-c3956cdb8184b1d366ba71cd147c7dd5.png
I, [2014-06-20T15:37:13.395060 #11433]  INFO -- : Writing /Users/alissaStandard/Sites/webapps/tfmpm/public/assets/edit-1465f360d78d4c9a879eab7d22808fee.png
I, [2014-06-20T15:37:13.398038 #11433]  INFO -- : Writing /Users/alissaStandard/Sites/webapps/tfmpm/public/assets/favicon-d181217fa230e0404d9a5439eef7b17b.ico
I, [2014-06-20T15:37:13.401578 #11433]  INFO -- : Writing /Users/alissaStandard/Sites/webapps/tfmpm/public/assets/favicon_lg-780640c6b50d13b9a0e2092d240e45b6.png
I, [2014-06-20T15:37:13.402822 #11433]  INFO -- : Writing /Users/alissaStandard/Sites/webapps/tfmpm/public/assets/incomplete-de002e821c78d4a784a02d4d6417f198.png
I, [2014-06-20T15:37:13.404142 #11433]  INFO -- : Writing /Users/alissaStandard/Sites/webapps/tfmpm/public/assets/list-c899aecf1c2e69a3d4dd31f8c42082c9.png
I, [2014-06-20T15:37:13.405375 #11433]  INFO -- : Writing /Users/alissaStandard/Sites/webapps/tfmpm/public/assets/logo-eba5f354bcc4b9809b19e1a6660d1c36.gif
I, [2014-06-20T15:37:13.421761 #11433]  INFO -- : Writing /Users/alissaStandard/Sites/webapps/tfmpm/public/assets/application-a871e88b8f786174f3a8da504335ac1c.js
I, [2014-06-20T15:37:13.467176 #11433]  INFO -- : Writing /Users/alissaStandard/Sites/webapps/tfmpm/public/assets/application-c3de85f47961d2b4326cf67a19887950.css
I, [2014-06-20T15:37:13.476147 #11433]  INFO -- : Writing /Users/alissaStandard/Sites/webapps/tfmpm/public/assets/bootstrap-4b23b275b16799cb1409b3d65104f8ae.css
```

I saw one other post that had this error but the solution doesn't apply because model user.rb file name is in all lowercase. Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: What does "user.rb" contain?

Comment: Updated orig post - thanks Steve!

Comment: Have you tried locally running precompile to make sure its not an issue that is also happening locally?

Comment: I just did - looks OK (updated orig post w/ results). TY!

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out - after running rake assets:precompile locally > git add . > commit to github. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline for more info.